# Keycloak returns "404 - Not Found" page

Tags: java, keycloak

I am trying to install Keycloak on my PC. I have the Java 8 JDK installed.

After running `\bin\standalone.bat`, when I go to the page `127.0.0.1:9990/auth`, I am returned the error

> 404 - Not Found

[image: screenshot of error page with title "Error" and body "404 - Not Found"]

Answer (score 7):

I had set a "Frontend URL" (`Keycloak Admin Console > Realm Settings > General Frontend Url`) for the realm that looked like this: `http://localhost:8080` while the client's "Root URL" was `http://localhost:8080/auth`.

After removing the "Frontend URL" everything worked fine. Another solution was to set both fields to `http://localhost:8080/auth`.

Answer (score 6):

The correct port for *Keycloak* is **8080**. The *9990* is the port for *Wildfly* administration.
Use http://localhost:8080/auth

Answer (score 3):

**update 2023:** the official docker image `quay.io/keycloak/keycloak` does not automatically points to admin console ( redirects you to `/` then `/auth` which gives you `404 not found`)if you want to access to admin console go directly to `/admin` instead

reference: https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-docker

Comment: I had trouble authenticating from /auth/ but /auth/admin worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked fine when I added --http-relative-path=/auth to the run command, thus my docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:19.0.1
    command: ['start-dev --import-realm --http-relative-path=/auth']
    volumes:
      - ./realm-config:/opt/keycloak/data/import
    environment:
      - KC_DB=dev-file
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=administrator
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=not-my-password
      - KC_FEATURES=scripts
      - KC_HTTP_PORT=9080
      - KC_HTTPS_PORT=9443
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:9080:9080
      - 127.0.0.1:9443:9443
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and then noticed that when I started standalone .bac, at the beginning of the prompt it said something like "JBOSS_HOME may be pointing to a different installation - unpredictable results may occur.", then if is that the case,  just
delete the JBOSS_HOME environment variable. I solved in this way. (I don't know how good is this solution, but i had no other ways to make it works)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with Keycloak running on Ubuntu image inside Docker.
What worked for me was adding `-b 0.0.0.0` argument.

So one can try running following command:
`bin/standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0`

You may be able to access console at `localhost:8080`

Answer (score -1):

If you will check keycloak [documentation](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_installation/topics/network/ports.html) you will get detail information about port that you can modify as well only condition that port should not capture by any other application.

```
 <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

So default port `http` its `8080` and `https` its `8443`

Answer (score -1):

In my case [the docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#_database) I read didn't mention to edit the `<default-bindings .... datasource=...` when adding a database. The server.log showed the wrong datasource name 'ExampleDS' which made it clear enough:

```
2021-11-15 18:32:29,302 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "keycloak-server.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.auth.auth.DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS]"]
}
```

So I fixed that...and was failing to connect to the database, because my database wasn't listening on the address it used.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to <host_goes_here>:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Reconfiguring  PostgreSQL fixed that:

/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

/etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf

```
host    keycloak    keycloak     <ip_goes_here>/32    <method_goes_here>
```

And FYI other than looking at config, you can use things like this to see what it listens to:

```
lsof -Pni | grep java
ss -ltp | grep java
netstat -lantp | grep java
```